# Safari reader mode does not show Lightbox images

Tags: image, browser, safari, lightbox, reader

I recently implemented Lightbox on my site to show images in a modern popup. It works great in normal website mode cross all browsers. But if i switch to Safari *reader mode* the images are not shown. And even badly: the plain text ends on the first image so the user can't read on. It seems that Lightbox, or the way that i used it in the HTML, is not compatible with the reader mode. What do i make wrong here? Here's the original HTML code.

```
<br><br>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: solid 0px #f0f0f0;padding: 0px;background-color:#f0f0f0;">
<tr>
<td>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<a href="bilder/artikel/g8bpart2/g8bpart2_000.jpg" data-lightbox="bilder/artikel/g8bpart2/g8bpart2_000.jpg" data-title="C64 &bdquo;Aldi&ldquo; (1987) mit empfohlenem Basis-Setup. (Bild:&nbsp;Stefan&nbsp;Vogt)"><img src="bilder/artikel/g8bpart2/g8bpart2_000.jpg" title="C64 &bdquo;Aldi&ldquo; (1987) mit empfohlenem Basis-Setup. (Bild:&nbsp;Stefan&nbsp;Vogt)" alt="C64 &bdquo;Aldi&ldquo; (1987) mit empfohlenem Basis-Setup. (Bild:&nbsp;Stefan&nbsp;Vogt)" width="660px" vspace="0"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="bild_text" style="padding: 5px;" align="center" width="660px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<span style="color: #333333;">C64 &bdquo;Aldi&ldquo; (1987) mit empfohlenem Basis-Setup. (Bild:&nbsp;Stefan&nbsp;Vogt)</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Reader mode removes stylizing, unassociated images, custom fonts, ads, social sharing buttons, and much else that can otherwise just distract from a webpage. 
 Safari Reader will detect a  or block level element that contains a header element ( to ), followed by a certain amount of text. The reader badge will appear when the content text (not including the header) is more than 2,000 characters. 
It is not designed to show popups like lightboxes, only in-article images and text in a readable form. It is based on [Readability](https://www.readability.com) 
In short, you will not be able to enable a lightbox for this, it seems

Comment: Thank you very much. The HTML code which includes the tables with the images gets included by a PHP Include. And even if i remove the Lightbox specific tags, the included Code is not shown by Reader. So this isn't a Lighbox issue. The issue is that the Reader does not show the code included by the PHP Include.